Did Paley justify God’s escape from his own watchmaker argument?
William Paley used the analogy of a watch to propose a designer of the universe. He argued that the complex structures of living things and the adaptations of plants and animals, similar to a watch, required an intelligent designer.
Given that Paley was a Christian, he also believed in a God who was not designed. Did he, in any of his writings, justify why God does not bear the hallmarks of design similar to a watch, but that the universe and living creatures do?

Not really relevant to the question as written but it's worth noting that Natural Theology was published 30 years before Origin of Species.

Yes, the question of whether the creator is self-existent or not is addressed at some length in chapters 23-24 of Natural Theology, which may be downloaded for free from the Library of Congress website. This is the same work as contains the watchmaker analogy. Paley argues that the creator is self-existent.

Nice succinct answer!
